# On different size of screens, Images are not aligned properly and size/clarity of image got reduced in android

Tags: android

I have created UI for android mobile 5.5 inch. But When I run it in different size mobiles image size/clarity reduced. Also images are not aligned properly.

Here is my output image for which I designed and how output looks like in different screens. 
Please help me

1) how can I make proper alignment for any screen size
2) Image size also should be increased if screen size increased.

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OizW.png)

**Here is my XML code:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/container" android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#003300"
 android:weightSum="1"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/containerroot"
 android:weightSum="1">

 <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:text="Review Card"
  android:textColor="#010101"
  android:textSize="24sp"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="#1c59b9"
  android:id="@+id/textView2" />

 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
  android:src="@drawable/revuename"/>

 <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:id="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_margin="5dp">

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


  android:id="@+id/containerrviewcard" android:background="#fc5ca8ff"
  android:weightSum="1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"  >


  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/closeFactsCard"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:src="@drawable/close_image" />

  <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="SUBMIT"
   android:id="@+id/submitReviewButton"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#060906"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10" />

  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
   android:text="1. The Food is:"
   android:id="@+id/textView4"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/closeFactsCard"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
   android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#010101" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/tasty"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/healthy"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/servedfresh"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/healthy"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/healthy"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/healthy"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/valueformoney"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/servedfresh"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/servedfresh"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
   android:text="2. The Menu:"
   android:id="@+id/textView5"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#010101"
   android:layout_below="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tasty"
   android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView2"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView7"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView3"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/servedfresh"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/servedfresh" />

  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
   android:text="3. The Catering team:"
   android:id="@+id/textView6"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#010101"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView5"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView4"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView6"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeFactsCard"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/closeFactsCard" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView7"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView8"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
   android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4" />

  <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
   android:text="4. The Food court:"
   android:id="@+id/textView7"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#010101"
   android:layout_below="@+id/imageView8"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView5"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView5"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView9"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_above="@+id/submitReviewButton"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView10"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView9"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView8"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8" />

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:id="@+id/imageView11"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
   android:layout_above="@+id/submitReviewButton"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
   android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView6" />


 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Alliance University Camous Food court"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
  android:background="#19d1e0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#020202"
        android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView"
  android:layout_margin="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot design a layout of an app to look perfect on different size screens, mobile or tablets. This is one of the reason why when you upload a project on the Play store you have an option to target the same app for different devices. However the good thing is the changes in layout are usually minor and easy to implement. http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Actually if found a link in that doc that says a single apk is the norm and designed so it adapts to any device configuration, i assume this maybe the way to have different layout withing a single apk and choose the appropriate one for a device at run time  -- http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SingleAPK